# ValueError: array is too big ... larger than the maximum possible size

Tags: python, scikit-learn, valueerror

Trying to work with a .csv file to build a basic movie recommender.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vector.fit_transform(movie_data['overview'])
sim_matrix = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

The last line causes the error "ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size." to pop up. Any thoughts on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: The full error message including traceback would be helpful, it tells you where exactly the error occurred. `maximum possible size` could refer to an internal limit in sklearn, or to your available memory. TFIDF vectors usually are sparse. Do you work with sparse arrays?

Comment: The full error message is ValueError: array is too big; arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize is larger than the maximum possible size and the traceback points to the last line in this code as creating the error. This my first project in machine learning so I don't get what you mean by sparse arrays. Is there any way to solve the problem of memory limit?

Comment: The traceback tells you which line in the sklearn source code led to this error. Please edit your question by adding the full traceback. If your `tfidf_vector` is a [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), try to use set a maximum number of features (`max_features`), so you reduce the array size.